# Swagger YAML generated by camel not compatible with Swagger Editor and UI

Tags: apache-camel, swagger

I have the following Camel Rest config. Both my Request and response body are plain text.

```
        <post uri="/swagger" produces="application/text" consumes="application/text"
              type="String" outType="String">
            <param name="body" type="body" description="Transaction to send" required="true" dataType="String"/>
            <responseMessage message="OK" code="200" />
            <route id="swaggerdemoRoute">
                <transform><constant>success</constant></transform>
            </route>
        </post>
```

The Yaml generated by camel is not compatible with Swagger editor and UI.

```
  /swagger/swagger:
    post:
      tags:
      - "swagger"
      operationId: "swagger_rest"
      consumes:
      - "application/text"
      produces:
      - "application/text"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "Transaction to send"
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: "OK"
          schema:
            type: "string"
            format: "String"
```

However, I can manually make it work by adding 2 lines after the "body" parameters:

```
  - in: "body"
    name: "body"
    description: "Transaction to send"
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string
```

Based on some input, I bumped Camel version to 2.20.2 and add dataType="String" in the "param" section. Still has the same problem. Additionally, an "operationId" is generated and Swagger complain its duplication.
How do I make it work from camel REST config?

Comment: What version of Camel and Swagger are you using?

Comment: Also try set `dataType="String"` on the `<param ...>`

Comment: @ClausIbsen, Thank you for prompt response. Camel 2.17, Swagger Editor is from Swagger host. Should be the latest. I tried add `dataType="String"`, still the same.

Comment: Try with 2.20.2 version of Camel

Comment: @ClausIbsen, tried both Camel 2.20.2 and 2.21. same result

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: @ClausIbsen  Updated my post with what I have changed

Comment: looking at the source code RestSwaggerReader line 327: String ref = modelTypeAsRef(verb.getType(), swagger); may need change to modelTypeAsProperty ?

Comment: Oh the dataType String should be in lower-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay looked into this some more and yeah its a little bug. I have logged a ticket and work on a fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12255